# How to hook up CSS search bar to JavaScript or another server side language

Tags: html, css, searchbar

I have a HTML/CSS template that included a search box, but I'm not sure what I need to do to make that search box actually work. Here is a link to the website http://teamb4p.ml 
Any tips or advice would be great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much will you pay for this ? :-p More seriously, could you please explain a bit what you have tried  or show some example code ?

Comment: @sodawillow here is the html code "<div class="search-bar">      <input type="text" placeholder="search" required="" value="search"/>      <input type="submit" value="" />    </div>" I am at a loss for where to go from here. I think it must need some type of server side script to run, but I am not really sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not commenting as I don't have the rep yet.

Try this tutorial, it uses the Google API.
You can copy and paste most of the Jquery and should only need to change a few variables.

http://tutorialzine.com/2010/09/google-powered-site-search-ajax-jquery/

Comment: Thanks! This surely helped me understand the direction I need to look, in order to resolve my problem.

Comment: Looks like I need to hook it up to JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks to your answer it lead me to finding another article that referenced http://www.tipue.com which is going to be the solution to my problem. Thanks again for taking the time to answer my question.